# Debugging kaocha tests or deftest in general?

Tags: clojure

Here is a small part about debugging in kaocha: https://cljdoc.org/d/lambdaisland/kaocha/1.69.1069/doc/8-plugins, which i do not understand.

Is there a way to debug kaocha tests or at least a way to execute a test directly from the REPL, so that i can debug the test?

Comment: Is this question about plugins or something else? Could you add an example of what you want, what you did, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about kaocha, but `deftest` macro just generates ordinary function by the test name passed to it in the test namespace:

```
(require '[clojure.test :as t])
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(w/macroexpand-all '(t/deftest a 
                      (println "before test") 
                      (t/is 1 1) 
                      (println "after test")))

;;=> (def a (fn* ([] (clojure.test/test-var (var a)))))
```

so, you just call it from anywhere you want, just importing the test namespace:

```
user=> (ns my-tests)
nil

my-tests=> (require '[clojure.test :as t])
nil

my-tests=> (t/deftest some-test (let [x 101] (println "x is " x) (t/is x 101)))
#'my-tests/some-test

my-tests=> (in-ns 'user)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x4c98a6d5 "user"]

user=> (my-tests/some-test)
;;=> x is  101
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but I tried Kaocha & didn't like it as much as the original Leiningen driven tests, especially with the `lein-test-refresh` plugin. Besides running from the REPL as in the other answer, you can also run either all tests or only one test from the command line.

With the [Test Refresh Plugin](https://github.com/jakemcc/test-refresh), the computer will watch your your source for any changes. Upon any editor save, the code will be reloaded & recompiled, then all modified tests will be re-run. The tests are typically completed before your finger has left the `<enter>` key.

You can see an example of using `lein-test-refresh` [here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template). Below is an excerpt from the README:

---

### Running Unit Tests with lein test-refresh

IMHO, the lein-test-refresh project provides the best way of doing iterative development in Clojure, re-running unit tests every time you save a source file from the editor.

```
> lein test-refresh
```

or make an alias:

```
alias lctr="lein do clean, test-refresh"    # lctr => Lein Clean Test-Refresh
```

with result:

```
Testing _bootstrap
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
result => "Hello, World!\n"

Ran 4 tests containing 6 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 07:56:48.252 (run time: 6.709s)
```

in this instance, the test output pauses after printing the elapsed time, and waits to re-run upon any file change. For example, make a simple change in the namespace demo.core by adding the word "Again!" to the println expression, and watch as the tests are automatically re-run:

```
...
Testing tst.demo.core
result => "Hello, World! Again!\n"
...
Finished at 07:59:53.863 (run time: 0.034s)
```

Note that the tests were all re-run in only 34 milliseconds (nearly instantaneous), since the JVM was already started and Clojure itself (plus library code) has already been compiled.

Comment: The same behaviour you get with kaocha, if you run it with `--watch`.